# Beamer - Multimedia : embedded autostarting mp3 file problem

Tags: beamer, multimedia

I have the following problem : I try to autostart an ambedded mp3 file.

If I use `\movie` the manual says I can't embedded the file but autostart works, with `\sound` manual says embedded works but I can't have autostart that should work.

I tried all examples with `movie15` and `media9`, nothing works, only `multimedia` gives some sound.

I tried AR 9.4.2 and 11 (it breaks during tests and I can't reinstall it).
Okular is operational.

How can I have embedded autostarting mp3 file ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Embedded but not autostart

\sound[autostart,inlinesound]{bob-1}{glass.mp3}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Not embedded (as written in manuel) but autostart :

\movie[autostart,inlinesound]{bob-2}{glass.mp3}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```